# Return value from subscribe in Ionic

Tags: return, observable, ionic4, subscribe

So I want to return a value from a subscribe function like this:

```
async obtenerListadoClases(categoria) {

  var clasesDB = await this.getClases(categoria)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
         clasesDB = data.clasesDB // **Want to return this**
         console.log(clasesDB,'clasesDB'); // **Getting Value**
      })

      console.log(clasesDB, 'outside'); // **Not Getting Value**
      return clasesDB;
  }
```

Also, I want to use this function in another place like this:

```
 var listaClases = await this.claseServicio.obtenerListadoClases(categoria); // Not getting the correct info
  //  console.log(listaClases , 'listado clases');
```

What Im doing wrong? Or how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the code from getClases() function please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only subscribe to **observables**.

**The Observable way**

```
getClases(categoria): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    // logic to return data
    observer.next(data);
    observer.complete()
    // logic when error
    observer.error(error);
  });
}
```

Return the getClases() function

```js
obtenerListadoClases(categoria): Observable<any>{
  return this.getClases(categoria);
}
```

Use the function where you want:

```js
this.obtenerListadoClases(categoria)
 .subscribe(
   result => {
     // what you want to do with the result
   },
   error => {
     // what you want to do with the error
   });
```

**The Promise way**

```
getClases(categoria): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // logic to return data
    resolve(data);
    // logic when error
    reject(error);
  });
}
```

Return the getClases() function

```js
obtenerListadoClases(categoria): Promise<any>{
  return this.getClases(categoria);
}
```

Use the function where you want:

```js
this.obtenerListadoClases(categoria)
 .then(result => {
   // what you want to do with the result
 })
 .catch(error => {
   // what you want to do with the error
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using promises with the `.subscribe()`. Only observables use `.subcribe()`

Also, stay away from promises in the angular world. Time to think reactive.

Is this returning an observable? `this.getClases(categoria)` post the code please.

Comment: async obtenerListadoClases(categoria): Promise<any> {

  return await this.getClases(categoria)
      .subscribe((data: any)=>{
      })
  }, btw im on Ionic 4

Comment: yeah ionic uses Angular. you should convert what you promise returns into an observable pudes user ```of``` de rxjs