# Return value from a subscribe (ionic/angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, return, observable, subscribe

So I want to return a value from a subscribe :

```
export class UserHomePage implements OnInit {     
    uid: string;
    ...

constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFireStore,
    ...
) {}

getAuth() {
    return this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {            <= // It's ok
    this.uid = auth.uid;
    console.log('ID : ' + this.uid);
 });
}
```

I try to use "this.uid" in other function but the data is "undefined" :

```
example() {                                                     <= // Problem !
    console.log(this.uid);
}
```

I just find an other subject on this forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278115/return-value-from-subscribe-in-ionic) but i dont understand the observable way.

Could u explain to me how to return this data for the next functions.

Thanks (and sorry for my english)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that your problem here is that observables are asynchronous, hence `this.uid` returns `undefined` if `example()` is triggered before your subscription to `this.afAuth.authState` returns any value.

The simplest thing you can do is to call `example()` from the subscription itself. Something like this should work:

```
getAuth() {
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
    this.uid = auth.uid;
    this.example();
  });
}
```